# "Link with editor" in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, editor, android-studio

What is the equivalent option in Android studio to Eclipse "Link with editor"?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you Google, use the Jetbrains IDEA knowledge base, or the online help?  SO is not an appropriate place to get technical support on a pre-release CTP product.

Comment: I googled it and couldn't find answer. And by the way - it the best place to get answers to issues like that.

Comment: The online documentation is the best, and correct place, to get answers for "how do I"?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's "`Autoscroll from Source`" in IntelliJ IDEA and since Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA probably that would be the same.

[image]

Comment: 10x!. To get the full effect of Eclipse "Link with Editor" - one should mark also the "Autoscroll to Source" option.

Answer (score 7):

I use Android studio 0.5.2, and there is a "cross" button in project explorer bar, it's "link to editor" in eclipse.
[image]

Comment: that is correct, but it will do it for the current open file, the above will do it always